# Call odeint inside Python class

Tags: python, class, scipy

I am trying to call the odeint inside a method in a python class:

from scipy.integrate import odeint

class Test:

```
@staticmethod
def mathfunc(y, t arg1, arg2):
    x , xdot = y
    #some equations
    return xdot, xddot

def numericalsim(self, y0, t):
    y = odeint(mathfunc, y0, t, args(self.param1, self.param2))
    return y
```

However, I get the error: name 'mathfunc' is not defined.
Please can you help me in calling odeint inside a class.

Comment: Python is telling you that it can't find `mathfunc` not `odeint`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you also share how are you importing your modules?
and since it's a static method you need to call it using your class.
like this :

```
y = odeint(SomeClass.mathfunc, y0, t, args(self.param1, self.param2))
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah that's right, you where faster haha plus one for you

Comment: I am importing them as from scipy.integrate import odeint.

Answer (score 0):

To call a static function you need to put the class name before the method, look at this full example:

```
def odeint(f, n):
  return f(n)

class A:

  @staticmethod
  def mathfunc(a):
      return a+1

  def numericalsim(self, n):
      y = odeint(A.mathfunc, n)
      return y
```